# How to redirect from Django views to a specific view of angular JS

Tags: angularjs, django, django-templates, django-views

I am working on something which has combo of Django and Angular JS. As the word goes, it little tricky to mix these two. I have everything working fine and so i decided to apply User Authentication. I have applied @login_required which redirects user to login page if not logged in , before checking out.

**`urls.py`**

```
url(r'^checkout/$','ecommerce.views.checkout'),
```

**`views.py`**

```
@login_required
   def checkout(request):
   return render_to_response('#checkout0',content_type="text")
```

**`app.js`**

```
 .when('/checkout0', {
            templateUrl: "../static/views/checkout-0.html",
            controller: "CartController"
 })
```

This anagular-routing is working absolutely fine when clicked through

```
<a href="#checkout0"> checkout </a>
```

How exactly to write `return render_to_response('#checkout0',content_type="text")` so that my page opens up with angular's `checkout0` view. Any help

Comment: why do you need to use angular routing actually ? I would just keep the /checkout django view. However, you could probably use a django redirect, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect being not permanent. A user could easily bypass the@login_required by getting directly to the angular route though.

Comment: Yes, redirect worked, Thanks!!,  but it can be bypassed as you said. I have the html pages in angular. does this mean that I'll have to do user authentication using Angular not Django :( . that would really break my heart.