# Can we rediect from Django view to some Angular View

Tags: angularjs, django, django-templates

I have been trying to google it out for quiet sometime but no luck. Can I redirect from Django view to angular view?

I mean normally when we return some some template file (like `homepage.html`), django looks into template or whatever dir we define and then opens up that html file. For Angular JS , we keep the `homepage.html` same and add `ng-view` in it, so that the html file stays the same ,only view inside it changes. The browser URL changes from

**Before clicking on Angular View:**

```
127.0.0.1/homepage
```

**After clicking on some button which changes angular view:**

```
127.0.0.1/homepage/#checkout
```

I have posted below question but no answer or solution has been posted :

[How to redirect from Django views to a specific view of angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063810/how-to-redirect-from-django-views-to-a-specific-view-of-angular-js)

Comment: why this new question after 20min since the first one ?

Comment: it was posted 1 day ago. i tried editing it 20 mins , but no replies. its urgent for me. I thought that may be its not clear enough